# Guide to installing and developing Ruby in windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Could someone be kind enough to point me to a comprehensive manual (preferably a book) that would give me basic, step-by-step instructions to setting up and using ruby in a windows environment?

I'm a complete noob at Ruby, gems and Rails.  Is it possible for me to get all-inclusive ground-up instructions on how to make web apps with Ruby in Windows?

So far I've read that rubyInstaller and Bash are a good way to use ruby in Windows; so inclusion of these tools would be a much appreciated bonus!

My biggest difficulty so far is simply getting bash set up so I can install gems and start coding apps against them (again I'm a complete noob!)

Also, what text editor/IDE for windows would be best for me to code in?

I would love an A-Z guide to installing Ruby/gems and making a Ruby-on-Rails app.

Thanks all!

Comment: Best book ever written regarding Ruby on Rails- > [Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) As for text editors - [RubyMine](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFEQFjAA&url=http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/&ei=9vcEUPv3GcfTrQeuwYGpBg&usg=AFQjCNEgOG_qLM1gg9YUEgAh7plc8nFQtA&sig2=ZYCywlRtxcxq46gi3nWH_w) is a great tool(Commerical). You can always go for [Aptana Studio](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFEQFjAA&url=http://www.aptana.com/&ei=5PcEUOx7iaqsB7XUzcYG&usg=AFQjCNEj5h0

Comment: If you're looking for a quick way to get going, check out [BitNami Rubystack](http://bitnami.org/stack/rubystack). It includes MySQL, Apache, Amazon SDK, a bunch of handy command line scripts to start/stop the services and quickly set up the working environment.

Comment: Here you will find my attempt to combine all the knowledge I gained while attempting to migrate an old version of RR application to windows. http://www.slideshare.net/vdimitris/deploying-ruby-onrailsapplicationsonwindowsfordevelopers Pay attention to the prerequisites and you will have no issues whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, personally I would suggest you to develop Ruby on Rails applications on a Mac or Linux machine. But if you really want it on Windows, there's a one-click installer for Ruby.

http://rubyinstaller.org/

After installing it, you can install gems through the command prompt that comes with the installation. If however, you want a quick start with Ruby on Rails, I suggest you try out rails installer.

http://railsinstaller.org/

There are a lot of good beginner books for Ruby:

[Learn to Program](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0976694042)

- A very nice and well-written tutorial on programming with Ruby. This book is for those who want a refresher on programming and want a nice introduction to the basic features of Ruby.

[Programming with Ruby](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356085)

- Also called the PickAxe book, this book provides a complete guide and reference for Ruby.

And for Rails:

[Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321743121)

- A perfect step by step tutorial and intro to test-driven development (TDD) using Ruby on Rails. It also covers useful tools such as GIT (version control system) and deployment using Heroku.

[Agile Web Development with Rails](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356166)

- This book guides you through a Rails project and examines Ruby on Rails in depth.

As for the text editor, I wouldn't recommend heavy or expensive IDE's, especially when you're just starting out. I would suggest you try out [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) which is free and lightweight, or you can try [sublime text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2), which has a free evaluation copy, it's a very nice editor and looks like TextMate for Mac.